# Given is a 2x2 matrix. Deduce a necessary and sufficient condition that this matrix is regular

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

> Given is the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix} a & b\\  c & d \end{pmatrix}$.
>   Derive a (necessary and sufficient) condition (equation or inequation in the coefficients $a,b,c,d$) such that $A$ is regular
>   and determine $A^{-1}$.

I'm not quite sure how such a condition is supposed to look like with these mentioned coefficients.

So I know that $\det(A) = 0$ is a necessary and sufficient condition for a matrix to be **not** invertible e.g. not regular. (Wikipedia)

From this it follows that $\det(A) \neq 0$ is a necessary and sufficient condition for a matrix to be invertible e.g. regular.

How do we achieve that?

1. If $a=0$ and/or $d=0$, then $c,b \neq 0$
2. If $c=0$ and/or $b=0$, then $a,d \neq 0$
3. $a \cdot d \neq c \cdot b$

So this would be a necessary and sufficient condition? Not really, in my opinion.. :(

The two sentences at the beginning seemed better but I didn't use any coefficients there as mentioned in the example task.

How do you do this correctly? I'm really scared of such a task in a test..

Comment: Assuming that $ad - bc \ne 0$, you can explicitly write down an inverse of $A$. If $ad - bc = 0$, then you can explicitly write down a vector $x \ne 0$ such that $Ax = 0$.

Comment: @user296602 Then the first you mentioned $ad-bc \neq 0$  should be the sufficient condition because this must be the case such that an inverse exists, right? But then what's the neccessary condition?

Comment: It is necessary *and* sufficient if you follow the two parts my comment.